# Undefined variable outside a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops

I've written code that grabs google fonts and adds them as an HTML body class. The code works fine but in my IDE, I am getting an undefined variable message. I can see why as the variable is outside the foreach loop.

```
 $fontstring = implode(' ', $families);
    foreach ($families as $fontstring) {
      $font = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+#', '-', $fontstring);
    $vars['classes_array'][] = strtolower($font);
    }
```

For the code above, `$fontstring` before the loop appears to be undefined.

This code takes strings from Google's api and strips out the characters to make them pretty strings.

```
<body class="Pathway+Gothic+One:regular">
```

becomes:

```
<body class="pathway-gothic-one-regular">
```

I can then use it within my Sass code for fine tuned theming, e.g.

```
.pathway-gothic-one-regular {
@include headings(uppercase, .02em, 60px, 9px);
// etc...
}
```

I've tried things like `$fontstring = array();` but that did not seem to help.  I also tried the `implode` function within the `foreach` but that did not work either. So I am at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: You are defining `$fontstring`. What about the item on the right hand side of `$fontstring =`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're using PHPStorm, I suspect you've not declared `$vars` (correctly) up front:

```
foreach ($anArray as $foo)
{
    //PHPStorm (rightfully) complains
    $newVar['array_vals'][] = $foo;
}
return $newVar;//<-- again, PHPStorm will complain, with good reason
```

Because `$newVar` isn't declared up front, there is no *real* guarantee that `$newVar` will exist outside of the loop: if `$anArray` is empty, the loop will not be executed, and `$newVar` is not created.
In addition to that, writing `$newVar[] = $foo;` is bad practice: you're accessing a variable that doesn't exist as if it were an array. PHP will create an array for you, but it will emit a notice if it has to access a key of an array that does not exist (undefined index error). This is the case if `$vars` in your code was not declared up front, because you're accessing a non-existent variable as an array with the key `classes_array`. In short: initialize the `$vars` array:

```
$vars = array(
    'classes_array' => array()
);
```

That should fix those warnings/errors. On to `$fontString`: PHPStorm also warns you if you're assigning a variable, and immediately re-assign it, which you do:

```
$fontString = implode(' ', $families);//assigning
foreach ($families as $fontString)
{//re-assigning in the loop!
    //more on the code here later
}
```

If you want PHPStorm to give you the green light, then you'll have to write something like:

```
$vars = array('classes_array' => array());//initialize
if ($families)
{
    foreach ($families as $fontString)
    {//a one-liner
        $vars['classes_array'][] = preg_replace(
            '/[^\d\w]+/',//\d == [0-9], \w == [a-z]
            '-',
            strtolower($fontString)//tolower here, so you don't need [A-Z]
        );
    }
}
else
{
    $vars['classes_array'][] = '';//empty string
}
```

I've pasted this code in PHPStorm, and got no warnings or errors whatsoever: all variables are used, and all of them are initialized when and where they should be. The way code I pasted in PHPStorm was:

```
protected function test(array $families = null)
{
    $vars = array(
        'classes_array' => array()
    );
    if ($families)
    {
        foreach ($families as $fontString)
        {
            $vars['classes_array'][] = preg_replace(
                '/[^\d\w]+/',
                '-',
                strtolower($fontString)
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $vars['classes_array'][] = '';
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was very close. In my case, "$vars" / classes array is actually a known system variable in another function higher up so I simply removed that at the beginning. This all works as expected now with no warnings in PHPStorm. I also rendered the page without google fonts and I don't get any notices or warnings from the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if(isset($families) && $families != null)
{
    $fontstring = array();
    $fontstring = implode(' ', $families);
    foreach ($families as $fontstring) 
    {
        $font = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9]+#', '-', $fontstring);
        $vars['classes_array'][] = strtolower($font);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works just as my code does but both `$fontstring` vars show as "unused local variables" in PHPStorm.